# Problemas con refresco de imagenes en chrome

Tags: php, navegador-web, cache

Tengo una aplicacion, la cual a traves de un formulario subo 3 imagenes, las cuales la ruta de estas se almacena en una base de datos y las imagenes en el disco en una carpeta especifica. La aplicacion tiene 3 "ventanas" que muestran una vista previa de las imagenes...

El asunto es, que al editar un registro, al cambiar alguna de las imagenes, si abro el registro nuevamente, sigue mostrando las mismas imagenes anteriores cargadas y no la modificacion que se hizo...

Revisando en internet, enconrtre que agregando un par de lineas al head de la pagina se evita el uso del cache, pero no me dio resultados:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
  <meta http-equiv="Last-Modified" content="0">
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, mustrevalidate">
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
</head>
```

Y tambien probe el agregar al principio de la pagina (antes del `<!DOCTYPE html>`), las siguientes lineas de php, pero tampoco funciono:

```
header("Expires: Tue, 01 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Este punto importante, esto **solo** me ocurre con los **navegadores de celulares**, no en navegadores de computadores.

Comment: Hola. EN efecto, esos encabezados le dicen al navegador lo que _debería_ hacer. Pregunta: en qué navegador estás probando?

Comment: @Alfabravo en Chrome de Android y en el navegador de Huawei

Comment: Evidentemente el nombre de las imágenes es exactamente el mismo, por eso se visualizan las anteriores. Una opción anti-todo es agregar un parámetro en la ruta a las imagenes. Puede ser el `timestamp` o un número de versión o el `md5` de la imágen, etc. Ejemplo: `/imgs/img.jpg?v=3`

Comment: Dependiendo de cada navegador, a veces se pasan de óptimos y suponen cosas para cargar más rápido y/o usar menos datos de transferencia. Prueba la aproximación que sugiere Marcos y/o revisa el uso de E-Tag en tus recursos estáticos.

Comment: Que mal suceda este tipo de situaciones y tenga uno que aplicar soluciones "parche". Les agradezco la informacion de por medio, tendre que optar a no cambiar los nombres de los archivos solamente...